# How to update EventSource schema

Tags: etw, etw-eventsource, semantic-logging

During the development of my custom `EventSource` I need to change the count and types of an event's parameters. Since I've used this `EventSource` for a while, it had already registered its events dynamically.

Is it possible to change or delete this registration?

Comment: https://slab.codeplex.com/workitem/68 add version to the Event and increase it. Or try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866212/slab-out-of-process-changing-the-signature-of-an-event-source-method-causes-in

Comment: Deleting the manifest file under C:\Users\{eventConsumerIdentity}\AppData\Local\Temp\7D2611AE-6432-4639-8B91-3E46EB56CADF solved the issue.

Comment: If you turned your comment into an answer I could accept it.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [to this question which was already asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31324842/1466046) deleting the manifest from the cache under `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\7D2611AE-6432-4639-8B91-3E46EB56CADF` or using a different version for the Event, which was [suggested on codeplex](https://slab.codeplex.com/workitem/68), should fix the issue.